# Twig: prevent parsing of client-side templates

Tags: symfony, twig

I need to output a portion of client-side handlebars templates, which has tags similar to twig's 'say' tags:

```
  <script type="text/x-handlebars">
    {{#view App.MyView}}
      <h1>Hello world!</h1>
    {{/view}}
  </script>
```

And twig attempts to parse these templates. How do I prevent it? Is it possible to mark a section of a template as plain text?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

There is [raw](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/raw.html) tag for this purpose:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
  {% raw %}
    {{#view App.MyView}}
      <h1>Hello world!</h1>
    {{/view}}
  {% endraw %}
</script>
```

### Update

As `raw` tag is deprecated use [`verbatim`](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/verbatim.html) instead.

Comment: Better check the next answer, `{% raw %}` is deprecated to avoid confusion with the raw filter, use the tag: `{% verbatim %}...{% endverbatim %}` instead.

Answer (score 25):

> {% raw %} deprecated

```
{% verbatim %}
    <ul>
    {% for item in seq %}
        <li>{{ item }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endverbatim %}
```

**Source:** http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/verbatim.html

Answer (score 1):

For bigger blocks of templates I would suggest to move those script templates into a separate file/files (where I suppose they should be to make all more structured).

Then render templates in your twig by using source command {{ source('uploadables-js.html') }} (IMPORTANT, no 'use' or 'include').

Answer (score 0):

To not litter templates with raw or verbatim tags, one can change [lexar](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/recipes.html#customizing-the-syntax) options to not conflict with client side template engines:

```
...
$lexer_options = [
  'tag_variable' => ['{~', '~}'],
];
$lexer = new Twig_Lexer($twig, $lexer_options);
$twig->setLexer($lexer);
```