# twig raw filter and functions

Tags: symfony, twig

Hi everyone and sorry for my english,

I have a service who generates some html code which is passed to a twig template. I had to use the raw filter to show the code, but in that code I call a twig function.

This is the code stored in a var which is passed to the template by the controller.

```
'<li class="active" ><a href="{{ path(\'help\') }}">Help</a></li>'
```

The resulting html code is the same, so `{{ path('help') }}` is not called.

Is there any filter to show the html code and call the functions?

Thanks

Comment: Your service should probably be a twig extension which you then call from inside of your template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, you are using {{path('help')}} for the hyperlink. Instead of using the twig path function, include the original Url in the code that is sent from the service. In the service. use

```
'<li class="active" ><a href="'.$this->container->get('router')->generate('help').'">Help</a></li>'
```

Comment: That's exactly what I've done, I included the container as argument of my service and it generates all the href using the router component. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I answered this before here: [Twig: prevent parsing of client-side templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9443313/twig-prevent-parsing-of-client-side-templates/17595881#17595881)

> {% raw %} deprecated

```
{% verbatim %}
    <ul>
    {% for item in seq %}
        <li>{{ item }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endverbatim %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should render your variable using the `{% include(template_from_string(your_var)) %}` twig block.

See the answer of [Render content from string/database and generate links with twig](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9803353/render-content-from-string-database-and-generate-links-with-twig) for more info.